# When are on-topic questions just crap?

Tags: discussion, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with questions from people who don't know enough to ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17803/how-to-deal-with-questions-from-people-who-dont-know-enough-to-ask)

I don't like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8948039/212940), but I don't know how to deal with it.

From the FAQ, "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers".

I fall in to the second part of that statement, but I would think even the professionals would know how to deal with a negative number :)

I don't think the question is off-topic, but....

I want to flag it, but what flag is suitable?

Comment: Generally, *not a real question* would be used for this.

Comment: @waiwai933 Yes, it could be a duplicate of that, although I had to read it a couple of times to realise. Although I'd like to think my question was slightly less angry :)

Comment: 89.27854% of the time? Note this is a very accurate estimation, based on my keen guesswork based on what I've been going through in the flag queue.

Comment: Haha, sounds like a reasonable percentage to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag to close it as `"Not a Real Question"`, because that's what it is.

But "hate" is probably too strong a word for some harmless bytes on the internet... Go grab yourself a beer and relax.

Comment: OK with the hate comment. I already had the beer :)

Comment: If I could relax I wouldn't be looking at SO at 01:25. But it's good advice.

Comment: and it wasn't "harmless bytes", it was `something wrong on the internets`!!

Answer (score 6):

If I were to flag that, I would probably go for "too localized":

> This question is **unlikely to ever help any future
>   visitors**; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific
>   moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not
>   generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

While this isn't exactly one of the scenarios listed, this question asks for a solution of a very narrow (negative number + toast) and trivial problem - this qualifies it as "not helpful for future visitors" IMHO.

Then again, I might consider the downvotes sufficient in this case...